# Duplicate log console when using Python logging module

Tags: python, logging

I 'm trying to solve this question for 3 hours. Please can you tell me what is wrong? These are my codes

```
import urllib
from jin import HtmlMigrate
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import logging
list2=[]
logging.basicConfig( format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
current = 1
source =""
for v in range(13960581, 13960585):
    list=[]
    try:
        fil = urllib.urlopen(source+str(v))
        fill = fil.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fill)
        k = soup.find("div", "post-taglist")
        for i in k.findAll("a"):
            list.append(i.string)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    if "python" in list:
        try:
            a = soup.find( "div", "post-text")
            list2.append(a)
            logging.info("%s question localized." % str(current))

        except AttributeError:
            pass

    current +=1
mig = HtmlMigrate()

out = file("stackover.html", "w")
for i in list2:
    mig.run(i, out)


out.close()
```

The problem is that I get duplicated entries in the console for each logger.info call. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you show us your console output?

Comment: have you printed list? are you sure you don't have any repetition of "python" in 'list'?

Comment: Waiiit... where is `list2` coming from? How does this code even reach the logger when it should be `NameError`ing first?

Comment: @user2357112 he simply forgot that piece in the code :D

Comment: Please make sure the code you post accurately reflects your problem. That means **never retype your code into the question box**. Copy and paste it.

Comment: ok, sorry I didnt paste my complete code.  This is my console output  INFO:1 question localized.
        INFO:1 question localized.

Comment: I am sure there is only one "python" in my list and it must write log msj only one times, but it duplicated. This is going to make me crazzy :((

Comment: Step through it in a debugger. It's a short script so just running pdb and pressing 'n' a lot will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my stab: you're *not* seeing duplicate log entries.  Rather, because your logging call is in a loop, you're seeing distinct calls to `logging.info`.

One way to (dis)confirm this is to change your logging call to include `v`:

```
logging.info("[%s] %s question localized." % (v, str(current)))
```

Let us know what that output looks like.

---

EDIT: OP has disconfirmed my theory; this answer is defunct.

Comment: This is the output :                                        INFO:[13960581] 1 question localized.
INFO:[13960581] 1 question localized.   Whatever I do, It duplicated :(( Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint just before the `logging.info()` call using

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

When you hit the breakpoint and are at the `pdb` prompt, type

```
p logging.getLogger().handlers
```

You should see a list printed with just one element - a `StreamHandler`. If that is not the case, then that would explain why you're getting multiple lines for a single `logging.info()` call.

Answer (score 0):

This material is from the standard documentation for the logging module discussing the use of `logging.basicConfig`:

> Note: This function should be called from the main thread before other threads are started. In versions of Python prior to 2.7.1 and 3.2, if this function is called from multiple threads, it is possible (in rare circumstances) that a handler will be added to the root logger more than once, leading to unexpected results such as messages being duplicated in the log.

If this is being called from some thread other than your main program thread, it may be the problem. I know this should have been a comment but I do not have sufficient reputation.